# Jenkins pipeline job hangs on simple call to print simple object from shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline job that has been working fine.  I have a small handful of similar pipelines, and I've been duplicating a small set of reusable utility methods into each one.  So, I've started to construct a shared library to reduce that duplication.

I'm using the following page for guidance: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ .

For each method that I move into the shared library, I create a "vars/methodname.groovy" file in the shared library, and change the method name to "call".

I've been doing these one at a time and verifying the pipeline job still works, and this is all working fine.

The original set of methods would reference several "global" variables, like "env.JOB_NAME" and "params.".  In order for the method to work in the shared library, I would add references to those env vars and params as parameters to the methods.  This also works fine.

However, I don't like the fact that I have to pass these "global" variables, that are essentially static from the start of the job, sometimes through a couple of levels of these methods that I've put into the shared library.

So, I've now created something like the "vars/acme.groovy" example from that doc page.  I'm going to define instance variables to store all of those "global" variables, and move each of the single methods defined in each of the "vars/methodname.groovy" files as instance variables in this new class.

I also defined a "with" method in the class for each of the instance variables (setter that returns "this" for chaining).

I initially would configure it inside my "node" block with something like the following (the file in the library is called "vars/uslutils.groovy"):

```
uslutils.withCurrentBuild(currentBuild).with...
```

And then when I need to call any of the reused methods, I would just do "`uslutils.methodname(optionalparameters)`".

I also added a "toString()" method to the class, just for debugging (since debugging Jenkinsfiles is so easy :) ).

What's odd is that I'm finding that if I call this `toString()` method from the pipeline script, the job hangs forever, and I have to manually kill it.  I imagine I'm hitting some sort of non-obvious recursion in some Groovy AST, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my "vars/uslutils.groovy" file in the shared library:

```
import hudson.model.Cause
import hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger
import hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger
import hudson.plugins.git.GitStatus

class uslutils implements Serializable {
    def currentBuild
    String mechIdCredentials
    String baseStashURL
    String jobName
    String codeBranch
    String buildURL
    String pullRequestURL
    String qBotUserID
    String qBotPassword

    def getCurrentBuild() { return currentBuild }
    String getMechIdCredentials() { return mechIdCredentials }
    String getBaseStashURL() { return baseStashURL }
    String getJobName() { return jobName }
    String getCodeBranch() { return codeBranch }
    String getBuildURL() { return buildURL }
    String getPullRequestURL() { return pullRequestURL }
    String getQBotUserID() { return qBotUserID }
    String getQBotPassword() { return qBotPassword }

    def withCurrentBuild(currentBuild) { this.currentBuild = currentBuild; return this }
    def withMechIdCredentials(String mechIdCredentials) { this.mechIdCredentials = mechIdCredentials; return this }
    def withBaseStashURL(String baseStashURL) { this.baseStashURL = baseStashURL; return this }
    def withJobName(String jobName) { this.jobName = jobName; return this } 
    def withCodeBranch(String codeBranch) { this.codeBranch = codeBranch; return this } 
    def withBuildURL(String buildURL) { this.buildURL = buildURL; return this } 
    def withPullRequestURL(String pullRequestURL) { this.pullRequestURL = pullRequestURL; return this } 
    def withQBotUserID(String qBotUserID) { this.qBotUserID = qBotUserID; return this }
    def withQBotPassword(String qBotPassword) { this.qBotPassword = qBotPassword; return this }

    public String toString() {
//      return "[currentBuild[${this.currentBuild}] mechIdCredentials[${this.mechIdCredentials}] " +
//             "baseStashURL[${this.baseStashURL}] jobName[${this.jobName}] codeBranch[${this.codeBranch}] " +
//             "buildURL[${this.buildURL}] pullRequestURL[${this.pullRequestURL}] qBotUserID[${this.qBotUserID}] " +
//             "qBotPassword[${this.qBotPassword}]]"
        return this.mechIdCredentials
    }
```

Note that I've simplified the toString() method temporarily until I figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

This is what I added at the top of my "node" block:

```
uslutils.currentBuild = currentBuild    
println "uslutils[${uslutils}]"
```

When I run the job, it prints information from lines that come before this, and then it just shows the rotating thing forever, until I kill the job.  If I comment out the "println", it works fine.

Comment: Does it also eat up all CPU? Sounds similar to my [JENKINS-41421](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41421). tl;dr try to remove the getters.

Comment: (Or rename to something that does not match `set<VariableName>`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the box, so it's hard to check CPU. I guess the getters could be the problem, causing a recursive call to each getter.  I'll test that.

Comment: I guess that was it.  Too much magic.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but apparently something like "return mechIdCredentials" inside "getMechIdCredentials" actually tries to call the same method recursively.  The correct reference is supposed to be "return this.@mechIdCredentials" (again, not yet verified).